Using orders to solve Diophantine equations
I am trying to understand how to approach the problem of solving a Diophantine equation (finding integer solutions) using the theory of orders.
Given an equation of the form $x^2+Dy^2=c$ for large $c\in\mathbb{N}$ values, are orders applicable for all values of $D$?
Observing an equation of this form, I tried looking at $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-D})$, which has the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-D}]$, so I believe the orders are $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{-D},\mathbb{Z}+2\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{-D},\mathbb{Z}+3\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{-D},...$ and so on.
Is correct? If so, I am unsure how to proceed. The main idea I had was to look for elements with a given norm.
